# JS, random Height

Tags: javascript, html

I want that my script add `72` small items, at the end it should look like an audio track. Each item should have another height from `30-90px` but everyone has the same height. I can't find my issue.. Thanks for your answers.

```
function frequencyContent() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 72) {
        $('.freqInner').append('<div class="frequencyItem"></div>');
        i++;
    };
    $('.frequencyItem').each(function() {
        h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30;
        $('.frequencyItem').css("height", h);
    });
};
```

Comment: you're changing height for all items with same css class, probably you need unique id

Comment: Thanks, i used "this" instead of ".frequencyItem" and now its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.frequencyItem')` will select all items and apply the css to all of them, in your case all the bar will set height as last generated random number. Use `$(this)` inside the **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** iterator to refer the current element in iterator.

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword ***this*** refers to the element. ( ***[Taken from here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)*** )

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 72) {
  $('.freqInner').append('<div class="frequencyItem"></div>');
  i++;
};
$('.frequencyItem').each(function() {
  var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30;
  $(this).css("height", h);
});
```

```css
.frequencyItem {
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="freqInner"></div>
```

---

You can even reduce the code by removing the **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** iterator by adding callback with **[`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)** method which iterate itself.

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 72) {
  $('.freqInner').append('<div class="frequencyItem"></div>');
  i++;
};

$('.frequencyItem').css('height', function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30;
});
```

```css
.frequencyItem {
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="freqInner"></div>
```

---

Or even more simpler by applying the css on generating the element, also [generate element using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
  $('.freqInner').append($('<div>', {
    class: 'frequencyItem',
    css: {
      height: Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30
    }
  }));
};
```

```css
.frequencyItem {
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="freqInner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adjusting the class each time, which changes each element with that class uniformly... Try adjusting each individual element using `$(this)` like so:

```
function frequencyContent() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 72) {
        $('.freqInner').append('<div class="frequencyItem"></div>');
        i++;
    };
    $('.frequencyItem').each(function() {
        h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30;
        $(this).css("height", h);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as what everyone else said but here's mine anyway version 2 is more efficient as it is all done in one pass on the first loop.

Please note that you have an acidental global with your h variable

```
function frequencyContent() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 72) {
        $('.freqInner').append('<div class="frequencyItem"></div>');
        i++;
    };
    $('.frequencyItem').each(function() {
        var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30;
        $(this).css("height", h);
    });
};
```

Simple one pass version

```
function frequencyContent() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 72) {
        $('.freqInner').append
        ($('<div class="frequencyItem" />').css(
          'height'
          ,Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 30))
        i++;
    };
};
```